# Customized Bugzilla whinning email format

Tags: bugzilla

The current email format is as below –

> ID, Severity, Priority, Plt, Assignee, Status, Resolution, Summary

What I need is as below –

> ID, Product, Component, Assignee, Status, Resolution, Summary

My bugzilla Version is: 4.2.4

I have edited below files but no avail:

`/var/www/bugzilla/whine.pl`

```
# Execute the saved query
        my @searchfields = qw(
            bug_id
            product
            component
            assigned_to
            bug_status
            resolution
            short_desc
        );
```

`/var/www/bugzilla/template/en/default/whine/mail.txt.tmpl`

```
[% FOREACH bug=query.bugs %]
  [% terms.Bug +%] [%+ bug.bug_id %]:
  [%+ urlbase %]show_bug.cgi?id=[% bug.bug_id +%]
   Product: [%+ display_value("product", bug.product) -%]
 Component: [%+ display_value("component", bug.component) -%]
  Assignee: [%+ bug.assigned_to %]
    Status: [%+ display_value("bug_status", bug.bug_status) %]
            [%- IF bug.resolution -%] Resolution: [% display_value("resolution", bug.resolution) -%]
            [%- END %]
   Summary: [% bug.short_desc %]

   [% END %]
[% END %]
```

`/var/www/bugzilla/template/en/default/whine/mail.html.tmpl`

```
[% FOREACH query=queries %]

    <h2>[%+ query.title FILTER html %]</h2>

    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th align="left">ID</th>
        <th align="left">Product</th>
        <th align="left">Component</th>
        <th align="left">Assignee</th>
        <th align="left">Status</th>
        <th align="left">Resolution</th>
        <th align="left">Summary</th>
      </tr>

      [% FOREACH bug=query.bugs %]
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><a href="[%+ urlbase FILTER html %]show_bug.cgi?id=
              [%- bug.bug_id %]">[% bug.bug_id %]</a></td>
          <td align="left">[% display_value("product", bug.bug_product) FILTER html %]</td>
          <td align="left">[% display_value("component", bug.component) FILTER html %]</td>
          <td align="left">[% bug.assigned_to FILTER html %]</td>
          <td align="left">[% display_value("bug_status", bug.bug_status) FILTER html %]</td>
          <td align="left">[% display_value("resolution", bug.resolution) FILTER html %]</td>
          <td align="left">[% bug.short_desc FILTER html %]</td>
        </tr>
      [% END %]
    </table>
[% END %]
```